# Pipe stream from io.Reader into POST without storing in memory

Tags: http, go, stream

**Application A** has a url pointing to a certain stored file. Can be stored on a disk, an S3 bucket or whatever else. **Application B** needs to receive a POST request, where the body is the content of what pointed by the URL, hence my file.
I have no access to **Application B**: what I think it's happening in there, and let's assume it's like this, is that it opens a stream reader towards the body content of the POST request. What I would like to achieve is that **Application A** passes the content of the file through a POST without having to:

- open a stream reader towards the URL itself
- stream the content in memory
- embed the content in the body of the HTTP POST request.

Of course the main part I am avoiding is the "store in memory" part.
So far what I did is:

```
request, err := http.NewRequestWithContext(ctx, http.MethodGet, fileURL, nil)

response, err := httpClient.Do(request)

req, err := http.NewRequestWithContext(ctx, http.MethodPost, ApplicationB_URL, response.Body)

res, err := httpClient.Do(req)
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work in my case because **Application B** doesn't receive in the Body of the http POST the content of the file, but receives an IO Reader. Hence, I am trying to achieve what above, without having to download the file in memory of **Application A**. Am I missing some concept here?

Comment: Are you sure Application B expects an HTTP POST where the body is the "raw" file? And not an HTTP form POST holding the file?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do here, but you cannot pass any sort of "file handle" like an `io.Reader` through http. If application B needs the content of a file, you must send that in the request (unless of course the application itself has some sort of abstraction for file location). There is no need to store in all in memory if that is your actual concern.

Comment: @icza yes, Application B expects the binary content of the file

Comment: @JimB oh? Code didn't complain about passing an io.Reader, but of course that doesn't mean it works! Application B needs the content of a file, yes, but how can I pass that without having to store it all in memory in Application A first?

Comment: You add the `io.Reader` as the request body, which will be streamed in the request. If that didn't work, please show a [mre] of how that did not work.

Comment: In theory what you've posted should work. Be sure to check all errors and the HTTP status in `response` (it should be HTTP 200 OK). If it doesn't work, it really depends on what you experience and what Application B expects. As JimB wrote, post a [mcve].